# Angular's UI-Grid on RTL Mode, displays missing columns on horizontal scroll, and columns horizontal alignment with corresponding cells isn't correct

Tags: angular, alignment, angular-ui-grid, right-to-left

I'm using Angular's UI-Grid with RTL mode, but when scrolling grid horizontally:
1. Relevant columns start not being displayed.
2. The columnDefs horizontal alignment with corresponding row's cells gets corrupted.
As described in [UI-Grid-RTL-Issue.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cwxQ.png)

Important: This behaviour only occurs when using Chrome, i tried opening the same page with I.E, Edge and Firefox and grid is functioning as the expected behaviour, also the behaviour described in attached image as (2) appears only using chrome

Below are the script and css imports am using:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular/1.7.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ui-grid/ui-grid.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.13/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui-grid/4.8.3/i18n/ui-grid.grouping.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui-grid/4.8.3/i18n/ui-grid.move-columns.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui-grid/4.8.3/i18n/ui-grid.pinning.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/ui-grid/ui-grid.css">
<link href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/excel-builder/2.0.3/excel-builder.dist.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.9.12/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.62/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

Note:
could the problem be caused by the following tag??:

```
<div class="ui-grid-header-cell-wrapper" ng-style="colContainer.headerCellWrapperStyle()" style="margin-right: --px;">
```

doubting the margin-right is being calculated in wrong way, please Advise!!

Comment: Similar issue was discussed in the following link:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=720227#makechanges
but didn't solve the problem, maybe the link has resources that helps solving the issue??

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, had to enable the "CSSOM View Scroll Coordinates" flag in chrome://flags/, and now the ui-grid is functioning correctly as expected